Pryor & Meylan mean
The title says it all, I read a paper which cites this mean, I looked in the provided reference but didn't saw any mathematica formula for the mean. Is anyone aware of it

"The title says it all" No it doesn't.

Please provide a reference to the paper

I am sorry, I thought that marking ProfRob answer has accepted would close this, but I think it didn't, so I appearing here just to explicitly say that his answer solved my problem.

There is no formula for the Pryor & Meylan (1993) mean. Equations 2 and 3 in the reference paper have to be solved through some sort of iterative scheme.
